# Dynamic search in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a WordPress site for a client, and I need a custom search box in the header. The site is using their external e-commerce tool from CNET. So the e-commerce pages in their WordPress site consist of an iframe displaying a URL to their CNET store.

So on the store search page, the iFrame URL looks like:

https://store.com/ourstore/Search/Category/?search_string=

Obviously, here you can pass in your search term into the URL string. So if I wanted to search for Dell Laptops, the URL to use in the iFrame would be:

https://store.com/ourstore/Search/Category/?search_string=dell%20laptop

What I need to do is put a search box in the header, and pass along the search term entered into the search box to the advanded search page, and put the search term into the iFrame's URL.

Is there a way to do this? I'm pretty new to WordPress, but I've been writing PHP code forever. I'm just not sure where to look in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you should be able to use the_search_query();

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query

This function just outputs whatever the current WordPress search query is. So in your code to call your iFrame, you could do something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://store.com/ourstore/Search/Category/?search_string=<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
```

Now, since the search term is going to need to be encoded for use in a URL, you can use the PHP function urlencode();

```
<iframe src="https://store.com/ourstore/Search/Category/?search_string=<?php urlencode(get_search_query()); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks good for displaying the results page. Any idea how to get a search box to go to my page "Advanced Search"? I'm looking at the Bop Search Box plugin below for displaying the search box in my nav menu. I'm just unsure how to direct the submission to my page.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bop-search-box-item-type-for-nav-menus/faq/

Comment: Couple of ways of doing that, but maybe the easiest would be to just set the search form's action to be that page's URL. domain.com/advanced-search, or whatever it is. Secondarily, you could save whatever page template that is displaying your search results as your theme's search.php -- this would give you full control over how the content is displayed, and may be the cleaner solution.